# How to automate an "onclick" if there's no element ID for that line?

Tags: javascript, onclick

In Javascript, I'm trying to automate an "onclick()", but the problem is that I don't know how to direct my "onclick()" to that element of interest.

When the element DOES have an ID though, I do this:

```
var redbutton = "document.getElementById("red_button")"

if (redbutton) {
    redbutton.onclick();
    }
```

But this time, after looking at the HTML of the page, my "onclick" of interest does not have an ID, so I don't know how to tell my browser to click it.
However, in the line right before it, there is an ID:

```
<div id="buttoncolor_pane" style="background-color: rgb(50, 50, 50); position: absolute; width: 400px; height: 200px; top: 30px; left: 0px; z-index: 998; padding-top: 25px; background-position: initial initial; background-repeat: initial initial;">
    <div style="width:140px; margin:10px auto; cursor:pointer" onclick="buttoncolor_submit('blue')">
    <div style="width:140px; margin:10px auto; cursor:pointer" onclick="buttoncolor_submit('yellow')">
```

Is there a way I can direct my code to that line, then tell it to perform the "onclick"?

Comment: If this is your code, you should add a class or an id, that would be the right way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelector) or [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll): (can be called on a node or `document`)

```
// get all div elements that are direct children of #buttoncolor_pane
var nodes = document.querySelectorAll('#buttoncolor_pane > div');
if (nodes === null) {
    return; // or do some other error handling
}

for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
    nodes[i].onclick();
}
```

You can use any query selector you like  as a parameter. If you just want one, use `querySelector` instead. it's the same, but instead of returning a NodeList, it returns a Node, so you can just use it directly.

In this particular case, `querySelectorAll` will only return one element, but I think you get the idea.

Or, if you really just want the first child, then use [firstChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.firstChild):

```
document.getElementById('buttoncolor_pane').firstChild.onclick();
```

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery, you can do something like this to trigger a click on the first child:

```
$('#buttoncolor_pane').children().first().click()
```

Comment: OP did not specify wanting to use jQuery.